# How to copy /var/lib/docker with overlayfs directory structure with data *as-is* without increasing the storage space

Tags: docker, kernel, rsync, coreos, overlays

I have a docker installation with several images and about 150Gigs of data in `/var/lib/docker`. This setup uses `overlayfs` as its storage driver. There are several directories for each layer under `/var/lib/docker/overlay` holding the actual data. The partition size is 160G.

My requirement is to copy the the docker directory from `/var/lib/docker` to a new disk of 1TB, so that I point docker to start from this new partition and continue to use my old images.

Now the problem is, when I use an `rsync` or a `cp` command with `-a`, to copy `/var/lib/docker` to new partition, instead of a total of 150G actual data, the total copied data is coming to as much as 600G (and counting..).

Docker is stopped as well, but not sure how OS is looking at the 160G data and copying into 600G+. I hope it is not the overlayfs (merged directories). There is no overlay information on `df -aTh`. Nor did it help unloading kernel overlayfs driver with `rmmod overlay`

How is it possible that I could just copy this data as-is, without any expansion/merge taking place.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It turned out that docker is using `hardlinks` within those directories under `/var/lib/docker/overlay`. Using `-H` with rsync (copy hardlinks as hardlinks) solved the issue.

```
rsync -avPHSX /var/lib/docker /new/partition/
```

Comment: note to self, if copying to another server, don't forget to restart docker on that server