# Copying docker image folder between partition with rsync

Tags: docker, rsync, disk, docker-volume

I'd like to move my `/var/lib/docker` data to another place, and to make it safe, i'd like to use `rsync`.

But the data are stored with sparse files, and rsync does not seem to handle it properly.

What would be the right parameters for `rsync`?

- `-a` preserves properly the uid/gid+rights
- `-S` handle sparse files efficiently, but rsync never seems to end

Without `-S`, rsync tries to copy more data than the original location can contain (100G on a 48G partition). With the `-S`, I seem to be stuck forever after about 10G.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `rsync -avXS` is working like a charm.

Comment: If you are using the overlayfs you should take care also of the hard-links hence the command would be `rsync -avHXS`. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39669414/how-to-copy-var-lib-docker-with-overlayfs-directory-structure-with-data-as-is

Answer (score 2):

Should you rsync a `/var/lib/docker` to a **remote server** be sure to tell rsync to do no mapping of the `uids` and `gids` between the two systems. Otherwise you could end up with wrong ownerships of files in your containers.

so this would create an exact copy:

```
rsync -avHXS --numeric-ids /var/lib/docker/. root@some.host.com:/var/lib/docker
```